# How to use Condion to generate Excel files based on dataframe column values Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create files based on below mentioned cells value **except value "-"**

for eg. if value == "-":
Then don't create file.
*else*:
create file for remaining all values

- i.e 642553, abc, 09pol_, -100

| File |
| --- |
| - |
| 642553 |
| abc |
| 09pol_ |
| -100 |

**My code**

```
for H_value in Health[columnName].unique():
        
        if H_value == '-':
            pass
        else:
            df1 = Health[Health[columnName] == H_value]
            output_file_name = "_"+ str(H_value) + ".xlsx"
            output_file_name = os.path.join(newFolder, output_file_name)
            df1.to_excel(output_file_name, index=False)
```

This code creating files for all values

kindly help me for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already know which column names to exclude, you can create a list beforehand containing all the values you wish to exclude,
and then filter over that before initialising your for loop. Here's the code,

```
bad_values = ['-','abc','-100']
#~ inverses the selection, so in this case all values except bad_values will be selected 
for H_value in Health[~Health[ColumnName].isin(bad_values)][columnName].unique():

    df1 = Health[Health[columnName] == H_value]
    output_file_name = "_"+ str(H_value) + ".xlsx"
    output_file_name = os.path.join(newFolder, output_file_name)
    df1.to_excel(output_file_name, index=False)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply, but its still creating files for all values including bad_values as well.